# Fitting data to the Poisson

Tags: chi-squared-test, modeling, poisson-distribution

As a part of my mathematics research, I am trying to model the traffic in my city.
I have gathered traffic flow count data from highways and city roads. I am using the Poisson model for distribution. The data I gathered sometimes fails the chi-squared test. In this situation, which other model / addition would you suggest? I want to basically also state the limitations of a particular model in heavy traffic and conclude the best type of model for different traffic flows.

- my data has 13 degrees of freedom ; the chi-square value is coming too large - about 3000
  what should i do in this case ?

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about how the data failed the chi-squared test?

Comment: The Poisson is based on assumptions that are only likely to be approximately tenable under specific conditions. It's possible for it to be more variable, or less. It depends on why it doesn't fit. Maybe you need negative binomial to get an adequate model. Maybe you need zero-inflation. Maybe you need a Poisson-mixture. Maybe you need something quite different.

Comment: Actual traffic data often *do* tend to look approximately Poisson--when collected over time at the same location. By including vastly different locations, you are effectively creating a *mixture* of Poisson distributions. The shape of this mixture intimately reflects your choice of sample locations. Therefore we have no basis to suppose it will be adequately described by *any* standard parametric distribution, nor would such a description--even if it were accidentally possible--be useful or informative.

Comment: With heavy traffic the traffic becomes more regular, so counts could even get underdispersed relative to the Poisson!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not been seen for years, so the extra context and info that is needed for an answer will not be seen